# quicker navigation in mc?

Tags: command-line-interface

Is there any way to speed up navigation in mc? I really like it for it's features, but I'm much quicker at getting where I want in zsh with tab-completion. Holding arrows to get the cursor to a directory I want is tiresome.

I know I can `Ctrl-O` and navigate there in the shell, but I was wondering whether there was an in-mc option for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CTRL+S/ALT+S` for fast filename search. This is only option, there is no auto-completion except ugly `TAB+ESC`.